# Site guest user profile CRUD missing in a new scratch org

Tags: salesforcedx, force.com-sites, profile, scratch-org, guest-user

I've got a bitbucket pipeline which creates a new scratch org with the following config and then immediately deploys the source into the scratch org.

```
{
  "orgName": "MyOrg",
  "edition": "Developer",
  "features": [
    "Communities",
    "Sites",
    "PersonAccounts",
    "SiteDotCom",
    "ContactsToMultipleAccounts",
    "ProcessBuilder",
    "ServiceCloud",
    "Knowledge",
    "Entitlements",
    "LightningServiceConsole"
  ],
  "settings": {
    "orgPreferenceSettings": {
      "s1DesktopEnabled": true,
      "networksEnabled": true
    },
    "knowledgeSettings": {
      "enableKnowledge": true
    },
    "entitlementSettings": {
      "enableEntitlements": true
    }
  }
}
```

As part of the project there is also the site guest user profile with the adequate permissions etc. What I noticed was even though the initial deployment/push is successful (and lists all metadata including the site guest user profile), when I login to the scratch org the CRUD settings are missing on this profile (everything else is there, FLS for example). If I then checkout the branch on my local machine and just do another deploy/push, it updates the profile with the correct CRUD settings.

Initially, upon completion of the pipeline:

[image]

Followed by another (second) deploy/push from my local machine:

[image]

I tried using both `push` and `deploy`:

`- sfdx force:source:push -u ${username} -f`

`- sfdx force:source:deploy -u ${username} -p force-app/main/default/`

but getting the same results. Any ideas why could this be happening?

**Update:**

It turns out there's some sort of delay upon the initial deployment and not all profile settings are saved correctly. I assume this could be due to the site and domain being created and propagated. As a workaround I'm doing 2 separate deployments, one without the profile (initially), and then a subsequent one including the profile:

```
- mv force-app/main/default/profiles/guest\ Profile.profile-meta.xml .
- sfdx force:source:push -u ${username} -f
- mv guest\ Profile.profile-meta.xml force-app/main/default/profiles/
- sfdx force:source:push -u ${username} -f
```

Keen to get some insight into why can't everything be deployed at the same time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that upon the initial deployment of a site/community, there's probably some post-deployment logic executed on the platform which leads to an issue with resolving some dependencies in the deployment package. It's not just the profile CRUD, but I also noticed the same with content assets. I have to initially deploy the site/community without the profiles and content assets, then subsequently deploy those components. This is a workaround and not an answer as to why this is happening. I would still love to see an explanation on what's going on under the hood.